# Circuit for Atmel (now Microchip) Single Wire Interface (SWI) using actual TTL UART?

Tags: uart

Atmel defines a Single Wire Interface (not to be confused with 1-Wire) for their [ATSHA204](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/Atmel-8740-CryptoAuth-ATSHA204-Datasheet.pdf) chip.

[AVR274](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AVR274.pdf) describes how to use a UART for SWI. But how to wire a generic TTL UART for this?(for example from a Raspberry Pi) Is it really as simple as connecting TXD and RXD together?

Comment: @VoltageSpike You were incorrect to delete my answer. It was not a question but obvious proof from the datasheet that it is a TTL UART, and my suggestion to teach how to tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, standard TXD and RXD cannot be connected together as TXD is always an output from Raspberry Pi or other TTL UART. It would push data line high while the Atmel chip needs to pull the data line low to communicate back to RXD pin.

If it is possible to make the TXD output as open-drain then it is possible to connect TXD and RXD together. Otherwise you need an open-drain buffer to handle that.

Comment: Ok, so wire up something like this:  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc2g07-ep.pdf to TXD to make TXD open-drain and pull-up the shared RXD/TXD-open-drain.

Comment: Yes, this should work as expected.